# How to Print Console.Log to JUnitXmlReporter using protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

I am doing a  protractor test. I want to print the messages i wrote inside the test using Console.Log("Message") to JUnitXmlReporter(the XML file).  OR .... is ther anyway to create a custom Output files using protractor. I want to print a Data i fetched from the test to a File.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters

from their page:

> JUnitXmlReporter - Report test results to a file in JUnit XML Report format.
>
> NUnitXmlReporter - Report test results to a file in NUnit XML Report format.

you can also create a custom one:

http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html

hope it helps

Comment: Hi Thanks . But i want to get the output shown in console to a file. Else i have to take snapshots of the console window each time. :) ... even if i use http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html i wont get the output to my reporter.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep things simple. You dont need any custom reporters to write the console information to a file. Just use the terminal output redirecting operator.

`protractor conf.js > consoleLog.log`

To append

`protractor conf.js >> consoleLog.log`

Check here for [more options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)